# Can I make inverse laplace transformation on time array?

Tags: python, transformation, mpmath

Recently I want to make some code to make inverse Laplace transformation.

I use mpmath.invertlaplace function.

It works quite well, but I want to remove for loop to get this result.

Here is an example.

```
import mpmath as mp
def func = lambda s: 1 / (s + k)

Time = mp.linspace(1,10,100)

result = []

for i in Time:

     value = mp.invertlaplace(func, i, method = 'stehfest', degree = 32)

     result.append(value)

return Time, result
```

Unfortunately, I cannot use array for mpmath.invertlaplace function.

Is there another library or function that I use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understood what you really want, but the code you provided above has a couple of errors that prevent it from working. First off, `func` has no "def" and it should therefore be:

`func = lambda s: 1.0/(s + 1.0)`

Also, `k` in `lambda`wasn't defined, so I made it equal to one (1.0) just to get the code started.

The code below works fine. Starting with it, you can (hopefully) change it to meet your goals.

```
import mpmath as mp

func = lambda s: 1.0/(s + 1.0)

Time = mp.linspace(1,10,100)

result = []

for i in Time:

    value = mp.invertlaplace(func, i, method = 'stehfest', degree = 32)

    result.append(value)

    print (i, value)
```

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much. It was my first question in stack overflow, so I make some mistake. yes. I make a mistake. I need to define k = 1.0 like you. 
Actually, my real question is 'removing for loop'. Because I want to make it faster.